# Swift rangeOfString index 0 or 1

Tags: swift, string

I have a array of Names and want to filter out those which has first OR second letter as "E", from the following array

```
var userNames = ["John","Tom","Ed","Ben","Albert"]
```

The outputShould be ["Ed","Ben"]. Albert should not be included as the position is not from 1st or second

```
let filteredNames = userName.filter { (inputStr) -> Bool in

     if let inputRang =  inputStr.range(of: "e", options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil)
     {
        //How do I check the position 0 or 1 here

        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let result = userNames.filter { $0.lowercased().characters.prefix(2).contains("e") }

print(result) // ["Ed", "Ben"]
```

This should do it.

Comment: Curious - what happens if there is a one-letter string in the array?

Comment: @rmaddy: Then `prefix(2)` returns just the first (single) element – the parameter is a `maxLength`.

Comment: $0 means first argument. Those are Shorthand Argument Names. You can find in the swift document https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Comment: @Eendje Can you suggest if have to use "inputRang" , how would I use it.

Comment: While this answer is a nice way to accomplish the goal, it doesn't directly answer the question (and I'm curious about the answer). How would you actually check `inputRang` to see if the result is 0 or 1? And I see the OP posted the same desire as I was typing. :)

Comment: @rmaddy: True, I have thought about what if he wants the 2nd till the 4th element. But since he only wants the first two and `prefix` does the trick, I just showed him this one. I've never used `inputRang` before and I'll try to find a proper answer (although knowing Martin is here, I probably won't have the time :p)

Answer (score 2):

@Eendje has posted has a good and efficient solution to achieve your goal, but to answer your
direct question: You would have to calculate the *distance*
from the strings initial index (`inputStr.startIndex`) to the position
where the substring has been found (`inputRange.lowerBound`):

```
let filteredNames = userNames.filter { (inputStr) -> Bool in
    if let inputRange = inputStr.range(of: "e", options: .caseInsensitive) {
        if inputStr.distance(from: inputStr.startIndex, to: inputRange.lowerBound) <= 1 {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Another option is to restrict the search range:

```
let filteredNames = userNames.filter { (inputStr) -> Bool in
    let range = inputStr.startIndex ..< inputStr.index(inputStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
    return inputStr.range(of: "e", options: .caseInsensitive, range: range) != nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Was wondering how lower bound could be used. Your answer helps too.